# Div is not getting hidden

Tags: javascript, html, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm pushing through a Google Tag Manager tag which has the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup')style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

This is targeting the `id` of a div that is currently set to this:

```
<div id="my-stealthy-popup" style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;display:none;">This is a rectangle!</div>
```

It does not appear to be doing anything to the div. Am I doing something wrong or can you not use JavaScript like this through GTM?

Comment: You're missing a dot in your syntax `document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup')style.display = 'block';` should be `document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: change your script to `document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup').style.display = 'block';`, one dot is missing

Comment: hi there, the tag is firing and I have made the changes as requested but it still appears to be doing nothing to the div, here is the url - http://www.yaroslavtroshchey.com/blog/hello-world/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have 2 syntax errors as below:

1. dot . is missing in

   **`document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup')style.display = 'block';`**

**correct as**

```
document.getElementByID('my-stealthy-popup').style.display = 'block';
```

2. correct **`getElementByID`** to **`getElementById`**

This is the running snippet

```js
 document.getElementById('my-stealthy-popup').style.display = 'block';
```

```html
    <div id="my-stealthy-popup" style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;display:none;">This is a rectangle!</div>
```

Comment: hi there, as suggested by others I have already tried this but unfortunately it still seems to not be triggering the change in the div on the page - http://www.yaroslavtroshchey.com/blog/hello-world/

Comment: check the updated **getElementByID to getElementById**

Comment: yep just saw the 2nd point you made, many thanks that all works now! :)